# How to exclude a country in a Shodan search?

Tags: shodan

I have a query I want to perform on Shodan that I want to exclude a certain country with.

I know I am able to select certain countries using the "country" filter like `thingy country:"US"`. But in this case I want to exclude the UK, using the country code "GB", is there any possible way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can exclude results by prepending a "-" to the search filter:

```
thingy -country:"US"
```

You can also search for multiple values at the same time:

```
thingy country:US,DE,CH
```

Here are some more example queries:

https://beta.shodan.io/search/examples